# jquery : find the element below one element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a simple application using jquery, in this application I can drag an element(DIV) along the document. I can place the DIV at any position in the document, If I place this DIV above another element how can I find out what is the ID of the element that is below the dragging object,

for example if I place the dragging DIV over an element I want to know the ID of the element below the dragging DIV

Thanks a log

Comment: does the `.elementFromPoint()` thing not work for that topic?

Comment: @jAndy: that's the way to go, though you would need to hide the div being dragged while you call *document.elementFromPoint()* and reshow it after the call.

Answer (score 4):

If you DIV has a specific ID or class you can use the `next()` function (documented [here](http://api.jquery.com/next/)).

```
 $('#dragdiv').next()
```

Then you can directly work with that jquery element or use `attr()` to obtain it's attributes (ID, etc)

Comment: I think the OP wants to know the underlaying element **before** dropping.

Comment: maybe I misread "above". I thought he already did the d&d part but didn't know how to reference to element that is after the div