# jQuery : drag and drop : find the id of the target

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing a drag and drop app. I have a DIV that is draggable along the document and there are some other divs in the document, I can drag one div to other divs, but how can I find the id of the div to which I dropped the dragging DIV,

I just want to know the id of the target DIV after placing another DIV over it.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery : find the element below one element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3943203/jquery-find-the-element-below-one-element)

Comment: You would have to have defined a droppable based on a selector.  You should know the ID of the droppable target already, no?

Comment: wild guess !! that div will become the parent div of the dropped one.. so using .parent and .children you may found that

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should be able to get the ID of the target from `this.id` from inside the event functions ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hPTB5/))

```
$(".droppable").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).addClass("ui-state-highlight").find("p").html("Dropped in " + this.id);
    },
    over: function(event, ui) {
        $('.display').html( this.id );
    }
});
```

[Updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hPTB5/2/) to make it clear that `this.id` works in any of the events.

Comment: If you need the id when you are over it it is like fudgey says, but if you need after the draggable div is dropped this.id should be in the drop function.

Answer (score 2):

If you use event delegation, though, **this** will be some parent of the target div.  In this case you could use:

```
var handleDrop=function(e)
{
    var target=e.target || e.srcElement;
    var id=target.id;
    // do something with it
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an event handler; it gives you both the one dragged and the one dropped on.

```
function handleDropEvent(event, ui) {
  alert('Dropped ' + ui.draggable.attr('id') + ' onto ' + event.target.id);
}

$('#someContainer').droppable({
  drop: handleDropEvent
})
```