# How to call JQUERY Draggable ID after it has been Dropped?

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggable, droppable

I am having a problem getting ui.draggable to work. I am hoping to be able to return its ID. All it returns is undefined, which I do not understand.

Here is my droppable call....

```
$( ".currqcontainer" ).droppable({ 
    accept: ".currqwrapper",
    drop: function (ui, event) {
        alert("dropped");
        var testid = $(ui.draggable).attr('id');
        alert(testid);
    }   
});
```

Here is my draggable initialization...

```
$( ".currqwrapper" ).draggable({ revert: "invalid" });
```

I am creating the currqwrapper instances with this script.

```
var $div = $("<div/>", {id: objectID, class: "currqwrapper", text: question});          
$("#currQ" + (i+1)).append($div);
```

If any of you could tell me why I am not correctly able to read the ID that would be great. Obviously I can provide anything else you need as well!

UPDATE : HERE IS MY CONSOLE.LOG(UI)It has the ID I need in there #ZiuFEYAcpP but I am not sure how to call it out?

```
toElement: div#ZiuFEYAcpP.currqwrapper.ui-draggable.ui-draggable-handle
accessKey: ""
align: ""
attributes: NamedNodeMap
0: id
baseURI: null
childNodes: NodeList[1]
firstChild: text
baseURI: null
childNodes: NodeList[0]
data: "ZiuFEYAcpP"
firstChild: null
lastChild: null
length: 10
localName: null
namespaceURI: null
nextElementSibling: null
nextSibling: null
nodeName: "#text"
nodeType: 3
nodeValue: "ZiuFEYAcpP"
```

Comment: Where is `ui.draggable` defined?

Comment: have u even do a console.log(ui); to see what it returns?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery : drag and drop : find the id of the target](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3943868/jquery-drag-and-drop-find-the-id-of-the-target)

Comment: Isherwood -What do you mean where is ui.draggable defined? Maybe that is what I am missing... The jquery.ui is linked from page. Also I am trying to get information from the dragged item not the dropped item.

Comment: @isherwood I added comments and console log.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/25089419/3886863