# Why can't I get Draggable ID when Dropped in a Droppable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, droppable

I am having a problem getting ui.draggable to work. I am hoping to be able to return its ID. All it returns is undefined, which I do not understand.

Here is my droppable call....

```
$( ".currqcontainer" ).droppable({ 
    accept: ".currqwrapper",
    drop: function (ui, event) {
        alert("dropped");
        var testid = $(ui.draggable).attr('id');
        alert(testid);
    }   
});
```

Here is my draggable initialization...

```
$( ".currqwrapper" ).draggable({ revert: "invalid" });
```

I am creating the currqwrapper instances with this script.

```
var $div = $("<div/>", {id: objectID, class: "currqwrapper", text: question});          
$("#currQ" + (i+1)).append($div);
```

If any of you could tell me why I am not correctly able to read the ID that would be great. Obviously I can provide anything else you need as well!

HERE IS MY CONSOLE.LOG(UI)It has the ID I need in there #ZiuFEYAcpP but I am not sure how to call it out? I notice it is in the toElement...

```
toElement: div#ZiuFEYAcpP.currqwrapper.ui-draggable.ui-draggable-handle
accessKey: ""
align: ""
attributes: NamedNodeMap
0: id
baseURI: null
childNodes: NodeList[1]
firstChild: text
baseURI: null
childNodes: NodeList[0]
data: "ZiuFEYAcpP"
firstChild: null
lastChild: null
length: 10
localName: null
namespaceURI: null
nextElementSibling: null
nextSibling: null
nodeName: "#text"
nodeType: 3
nodeValue: "ZiuFEYAcpP"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have reversed the parameters on the drop event.
instead of

```
drop: function (ui, event) {...
```

write

```
drop: function (event, ui) {
```

Comment: Oh my gosh. I spent hours on that. Thanks!