# Using jquery draggable and droppable how to get element id from some list element?

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

If I select img element : `.img_2` then I drag  to li element : `list_5`

how to  get that class name?

This jquery code can't get list_5

I use "$('li').hover() " get data etc....

But I can't get class name

```js
  

  $('.dragable').draggable({
 handle: "img",
        helper: "clone",
        revert: 'valid',
        cursor: 'move', start: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).draggable('instance').offset.click = {
                left: Math.floor(ui.helper.width() / 2),
                top: Math.floor(ui.helper.height() / 2)
            };
            console.log($(this).data("dropzone"))
            $(".ui-draggable-dragging").css('opacity', "0.2")
  
       
        }})
    $('.droppableList').droppable({
      drop: function(e, u) {

        var droppableId = $(this).attr("class");
        console.log(droppableId)
//i want to get li element of class name "list_5"
      }
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js2" rel="stylesheet" />

<ul class="droppableList">
  <li class="list_1"> a</li>
  <li class="list_2"> b</li>
  <li class="list_3"> c</li>
  <li class="list_4">
    <ul class="list_1_2">

      <li class="list_5">d</li>
      <li class="list_6">e</li>
      <li class="list_7">f</li>

    </ul>
  </li>
  </ul>

  <div class="dragable">
    <img class="img_1" src="https://via.placeholder.com/468x60?text=image1"/>
    <img class="img_2" src="https://via.placeholder.com/468x60?text=image2"/>
  </div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please fix into a [mcve]

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. ***[Do some research](https://www.google.com/search?q=droppable+get+target+site:stackoverflow.com)***, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: Yes. i already  looking that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3943868/jquery-drag-and-drop-find-the-id-of-the-target. but that didn't solve it