# Grabbing a reference to the element closest to scrollTop

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering how to grab a reference to whatever DOM node happens to be closest to `document.body.scrollTop` at any given time.

Let's say I had 10 paragraphs inside a `div`, and the `scrollTop` at 400px is on `p` child 5.

I want to store that information and return the user to that paragraph when they come back. Of course I could simply reset the scrollTop to a given value, but if the browser is resized or the orientation is changed, this isn't a reliable method (and media queries might alter the size of elements).

However, if I could store the value of the node at the top, I can use `.scrollIntoView()` and be sure the user is in the correct location.

Any thoughts?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you used jQuery? the `.next()` function may be helpful - example in [-This-](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3943203/jquery-find-the-element-below-one-element) question.

Comment: `.next()` is very helpful for traversing the DOM and perhaps for grabbing the DOM node at the top of the document. But in this case, I want to grab the element that is _visually_ at the top of the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy enough if you know the document structure. To continue your example:

```
// div is the parent <div> element
var el, top, min = Number.MAX_VALUE, els = div.getElementByTagName('p');
for (var i=0; i<els.length; i++) {
    top = Math.abs(els[i].getBoundingClientRect().top);
    if (top < min) {
        min = top;
        el = els[i];
    }
}

// el now holds the <p> whose top is closest to the top of the window
```

Comment: This is fantastic. I made a few changes for my purposes—instead of storing the element, I'm storing its position in the array of elements (this way, I can return a user to the paragraph above (if there is one) so they can get a running start, or start from a more familiar paragraph). 

Do you mind if I repost the answer below with extra comments explaining what's happening for those who come looking for something similar?